# Turn multiple input statements into a loop?

Tags: c++

Ok, i have this function with 5 variables. score1-score5. Instead of repeating the prompt for user input 5 times in my code is there a way i can use a loop to store the user input and go through each iteration as well? This is homework but it doesn't really matter anymore since i have the program working fine, i would just like to clean up the code a bit. I cannot use an array here either. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
void getScore(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3, double &score4, double &score5)
{   
    cout << "Enter a score: ";
    cin >> score1;
    cout << "Enter a score: ";  
    cin >> score2;
    cout << "Enter a score: ";  
    cin >> score3;
    cout << "Enter a score: ";  
    cin >> score4;
    cout << "Enter a score: ";
    cin >> score5;
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
```

Comment: You could use an array instead of five arguments.

Comment: I'm guessing not std:vectors are allowed either.  In that case you can't loop.

Comment: Per professors instructions, no array. Trust me i would have done so by now!

Comment: the loop would go in whichever function is calling the getScore method. (and change that to double getScore( string prompt ))

Comment: Yes, use a container and loop. You should learn the Zero-One-Many rule: The only literal numbers in programming should be 0 and 1 (and maybe -1), and anything that comes in "many" instances should be a container plus loop.

Comment: You might be able to exploit compiler specific automatic allocation [after all, all the variables are on stack] and access the stack directly to modify them  - but it will cause undefined behavior for any other compiler, and I strongly advise against it...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `std::vector<double>` as:

```
std::vector<double> readScore(int count)
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        double score;
        std::cout << "Enter a score: ";
        std::cin >> score;
        v.push_back(score);
    }
    return v;
}

std::vector<double> scores = readScore(5);
```

---

If you cannot change the function parameters, and have to stick to 5 parameters,then you can do something like this:

```
void getScore(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3, double &score4, double &score5)
{
     //store the address of each parameter in an array of pointers
     double *input[] = {&score1,&score2,&score3,&score4,&score5};
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
     {
          std::cout << "Enter a score : ";
          std::cin >> *input[i]; //it reads into parameters!
     }
}
```

In this solution, you first store the address of each parameter in an array of pointers, then you use the array of pointers in a loop, to read the scores. Since `input[i]` is an address of one of the parameter, depending on the value of `i`, so `std::cin >> *input[i]` will read user-input and store it at the same address where `input[i]` is pointing to, which is nothing but one of the parameter.

Comment: I would love to if it would work but i have not learned that in class yet and have to stick to parameters of what has been taught as of yet.

Comment: I cannot use an array either. Thank you for the suggestions though. If it cannot be done without an array or vector than its no biggie. Its only a few lines of code.

Comment: @Gmenfan83: Then you cannot use loop.

Answer (score 3):

Without the user of a data structure holding the values you won't be able to use a loop. However, you can factor the actual reading into a function to avoid some level of code duplication:

```
bool getScore(double& score)
{
    std::cout << Enter a score: ";
    return std::cin >> score;
}

bool getScore(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3, double &score4, double &score5)
{
    return getScore(score1)
        && getScore(score2)
        && getScore(score3)
        && getScore(score4)
        && getScore(score5);
}
```

This example also adds some error checking: all inputs to a program need to be checked. Without this, you'll end up processing random data upon any input error.